# Intellij Idea freezes/hangs with kendo script type in html/tml file

Tags: html, intellij-idea, kendo-ui, tapestry

Adding the below script to my html (or .tml for apache tapestry) file hangs Intellij.

Once I remove this code, it works fine.

I am using Intellij Idea 16.1. This happens on other people who use this script as well. It does not happen for people using Eclipse, so definitely an Idea issue. How can I stop the IDE freezing over if this script is introduced in the html/tml file?

```
            <script id="notificationTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
                <p style="width: 16em; padding:1em;white-space:nowrap"> #= kValue # </p>
            </script>
```